# Как изменить label в Jira, используя библиотеку go-jira?

Tags: golang, rest, jira

Вижу, что есть функция UpdateIssue, судя по описанию REST API Jira есть возможность поменять поле Labels (метки), но никак не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Используется https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira

Comment: [`IssueService.Update`](https://godoc.org/github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira#IssueService.Update)? Там же есть поле `Issue.Fields.Labels`.

Comment: @Ainar-G, это функция обновления json для определенной issue. Она возвращает структуру *Response с телом тикета.